# Remove words from a data.frame with a pattern

Tags: regex, r

How can I remove from a data.frame all words ending with `_at`? 
I tried something like:

```
gsub('\\S+_at\\S+', '', mydf)
```

I'm doing wrong for sure since it does not work.

Comment: Please show some example ie. `mydf`

Comment: If `v1<-  c('atzte zat_at', '132_a a3343_at', 't1332_at t13at', '5123_ta');
 gsub('\\w+_at', '', v1)`

Comment: @akrun's answer will also remove the first part of words with '_at' in the middle.  you may want `gsub('\\w+_at($|\\s)', '\\1', v1) instead
`

Comment: What about `\\s*\\w+_at\\b`. The beginning `\\s*` captures leading space before the word. That way `My dog is big_at!` doesn't become `My dog is !`